# variable path in href tag

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

```
<a id="m1" class="audio {autoPlay:false, addGradientOverlay:true}"
href="MusicFolder/" + document.getElementById("DropDownList1").value +  "/" +
document.getElementById("DropDownList2").value>document.getElementById("DropDownList2").value</a>
```

I got above code in my aspx web page but its not working.  I am trying to get variable file path by combining two dropdowns selected values.  Please can anybody help that what I am doing wrong and how can I correct above code.

Drowpdown asp.net code is below

```
        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" id="DropDownList1" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource6" DataTextField="TranslationLang" DataValueField="TranslationLang" Height="25px" Width="100%"></asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource6" runat="server" DataFile="Database/HFx.mdb" SelectCommand="SELECT [TranslationLang] FROM [Translation]">
        </asp:AccessDataSource>
        <br />
        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" id="DropDownList2" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource7" DataTextField="Surah" DataValueField="Surah" Height="25px" Width="100%"></asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource7" runat="server" DataFile="Database/HFx.mdb" SelectCommand="SELECT [Surah] FROM [TranslationSurah] WHERE ([Lang] = ?) ORDER BY [No]">
        <SelectParameters>
        <asp:controlparameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="Lang" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
        </asp:AccessDataSource>
```

Comment: please post dropdown markup

Comment: sorry what you mean by markup.  If you mean my asp.net code for the dropdowns then I've added that for you above in my original question.

Answer (score 0):

Browser executes the JS inside an href only when it is clicked but for that you need to mention "javascript:" at the beginning of content inside href. The following code should work

```
<a id="m1" class="audio {autoPlay:false, addGradientOverlay:true}"
href="javascript:window.location='MusicFolder/' + document.getElementById('DropDownList1').value +  '/' + document.getElementById('DropDownList2').value">document.getElementById('DropDownList2').value</a>
```

Comment: Oh! I have written a very simple HTML page(http://jsbin.com/gexovawamo/1/edit) where I am setting the target of an href by reading the content of an another node. There it works. My guess is there is problem at some other places in your code. Probably you can start with http://jsbin.com/gexovawamo/1/edit and then add your staff gradually to see where it breaks. Thanks.